# auth()->attempt() in Laravel 5.5 did'nt work properly

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5

I already create a simple login without hash for make it easier to understand but my auth always throw error message, I've searching the solution but still has the same result.

This is my cotroller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

//Class needed for login and Logout logic
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

//Auth facade
use Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['auth']]);
    }

    public function auth()
    {
       if (auth()->check()) 
       {
         return redirect()->userDash();
       }
       else 
       {
         if (auth()->attempt([
                'email'     => request('email'),
                'password'  => request('password')
            ]))
         {
            return redirect()->userDash();
         }
         else
         {
           return back()->withErrors([
           'message' => 'Please Check Your Credentials !'
          ]);
         }             
       }
    }
```

This is route

```
Route::POST('/login', 'AuthController@auth');
```

This is my db

[image]

And this is the result when I debug input email and password

[image]

I think all is right, maybe need some correction if there have a wrong code for login method. Thank you.

Comment: Your password isn't hashed, it'll never work.

Comment: so I need to hash my password configuration ?

Comment: Your password needs to be stored in the database using the `hash::make` method.

Comment: It works ! Thank You @Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must encrypt the password using `bcrypt()` or `Hash::make()` methods and use use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` in your login controller.
for more [details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication)

Answer (score 3):

Laravel use bcrypt() method to encrypt the password. You need to use the bcrypt method while registering a user. like: `bcrypt(request('password'))`

Answer (score 0):

Just Add Hash::make method in your registration method, it will works, thank you !